# Openstack cloud provider with rke2

Tags: rancher, rke2

I am setting up a rke2 cluster with rancher on Openstack.

**Environment:**

- custom provisioned resources in Openstack (network, instances etc.)
- Rancher running on one of the instances
- a couple of instances to serve as cluster nodes (masters and workers)

**Context:**

When setting up **rke2** cluster via Rancher, I need to define a cloud provider so that nodes are properly set up with *providerID* (so that plugins such as openstack cloud controller manager or cinder csi are able to identify node in Openstack).

With **rke** I am able to define Openstack as a cloud provider along with its configuration via yaml in rancher as described in their [official documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/cloud-providers/openstack/). This way **rke** will make sure to update nodes with *providerID* when setting nodes up automatically.

**Problem:**

It does not seem to be possible to define Openstack specific configuration when creating **rke2** cluster.
As for the External cloud provider, I was not able to find any information about how to define that this is in reality an Openstack cluster and how to define configuration so that **rke2** is able to properly work with it.
[image]

**Questions**

1. Is **rke2** able to use Openstack as cloud provider or is this available only on **rke**?
2. Is there any documentation or do you guys have any tip how to properly setup Openstack as a cloud provider for **rke2**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out it is possible to define cloud provider for Openstack. The problem I faced was due to very strict definition of Cloud Provider Config for Openstack in Rancher. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714756/kublet-doesnt-start-with-cloud-provider-openstack), the problem was with unexpected fields that I had in the configuration. After removing all unnecessary fields it all came up as expected. Unfortunately, no error messages really let you know that it has issues with some unrequired fields.

Comment: Hi @klodye, can you share your configuration here? I'm in the same boat and cannot find any documentation for creating RKE2 clusters on Openstack, using Rancher.